# Read COM port response with VBA 2

Tags: vba, ms-access

Good morning, I would like to receive a reply from the COMx port to which an RS485 card with 8 relays is connected to find out the status of the individual relays. I can send the ON / OFF commands with the following command `FF 01 01/00` which is equivalent to the code.

```
Open "COM4: 9600, N, 8.1" For Binary As # 1

Put # 1,, Chr (& HFF) & Chr (& H1) & Chr (& H1)/(&H0)

Close # 1
```

To know its status the command is `FF A1 00` whose answer is `FF A1 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00` but I can't find a way to write it in VBA.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your code looks wrong.

It likely works, since sending FF 01 01 is perhaps ok.

However, you need that "/" in the text stream.

So, that line of code should be:

```
Put #1, , Chr(&HFF) & Chr(&HA1) & Chr(&H1) & "/" & chr(&H0)
```

Or, since "/" is 47 in ASCII, then this would also be fine:

```
Put #1, , Chr(&HFF) & Chr(&HA1) & Chr(&H1) & chr(47) & chr(&H0)
```

And, 47 (a "/") in HEX is 2F

So, this would work:

```
Put #1, , Chr(&HFF) & Chr(&HA1) & Chr(&H1) & chr(&H2F) & chr(&H0)
```

So, what you need for the 2nd command?

You want to output this FF A1 00

```
Put #1, , Chr(&HFF) & Chr(&HA1) & Chr(&H0)
```

Now, likely over time, you have all kinds of commands. And writing the above is rather hard,

So, you would do well to say create a routine that you can call.

So, it would look like this:

```
Sub WriteCommand(strCommand As String)

  Dim strBuf  As String
  Dim i       As Integer
  strBuf = ""
  For i = 1 To Len(strCommand) Step 3
     strBuf = strBuf & Chr("&H" & Mid(strCommand, i, 2))
  Next i

  Open "COM4: 9600, N, 8.1" For Binary As #1
     Put #1, , strBuf
  Close #1

End Sub
```

What the above requires then is you to pass a string, and it will covert it for you.

So, for example, your first command is this:

FF 01 01/00

Now, in above the "/" is part of the issue. the "/" is actually 47 from the ASCII table.

So, the above would be written as

FF 01 01 2F 00

So, our routine to send above would be:

Sub Ctestwr()

```
  Dim strCommand    As String      
  ' Note that hex 47 = / = 2F in hex
  strCommand = "FF 01 01 2F 00"
  Call WriteCommand(strCommand)

End Sub
```

So, to send your 2nd command, you would/could now go:

```
Call WriteCommand("FF A1 00")
```

Now, I suspect that in many cases, after you send a command, you likely want to wait or get the response back. It not clear if the device sends a result and THEN a return key, or that the result is ALWAYS the same length. You would do well to find out this information, as then the NEXT routine you would write would combine the above code, and some code to return/grab/get the response back, and likely covert it back to a nice HEX string with spaces between each value.

So, with the above simple routine:

You can easy send any command.
Just keep in mind that you can't use the "/" in the string - you have to replace it with 47 (&H2F) (but just write this number down).

So, now to send any command, you can just do this:

```
Sub Ctestwr()

  ' Note that hex 47 = / = 2F in hex

  Call WriteCommand("FF 01 01 2F 00")

End Sub
```

Now, once the above is working, then you can use the above, or create a new command that sends a command, and also returns the response back.

So, you could go:

```
 dim strResult   as string

 strResult = CmdAndResponse("FF 01 01 2F 00")
 ' strResult would now have the response sent from the machine
```

So, the idea here is you built a routine to send a command. And it oh so easy to use, since now we can just type in a hex string (with a space between each value).
It would write out the string as binary values.
And then it would wait for the response, and spit that back to you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to follow your advice and it works to send commands.
I tried to write a routine for strResult

```
Sub CmdAndResponse(strResult As String)
Dim strBuf  As String
Dim i       As Integer
strBuf = ""
For i = 1 To Len(strResult) Step 3
    strBuf = strBuf & Chr("&H" & Mid(strResult, i, 2))
Next i
Open "COM4: 9600,N,8,1" For Binary As #1
    Put #1, , strBuf
Close #1
End Sub
```

and the routine that calls

```
Sub Ctestres()
Dim strResult As String
strResult = CmdAndResponse("FF A1 00")
MsgBox (strResult) & " " & Len(strResult)
End Sub
```

but I get the error "Expected Function or variable".

If instead I write for strResult as a function and not as a routine, no error is generated, I see the RX led of the relay board which flashes, but after execution strResult does not contain any response

Comment: The CommandAndReponse was a suggestion for the future enhancements. The first example where I go:  Call WriteCommand("FF A1 00") is how you use the sample    We never write the CmdAndREsponse() function - that was a suggestion if the device actually returns values --- that was a future suggestion.

Comment: unfortunately I am unable to go on without help. thanks anyway